# Возможны ли обязательные метки на основном сайте?

Tags: обсуждение

На мете есть список обязательных тегов, хотя бы один из которых должен присутствовать, чтобы можно было задать вопрос: [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Возможна ли подобная функциональность на основном сайте?

PS: Зачем надо, объясню потом.

PPS: [Feature request на codegolf'e](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8809/32091) (оттуда сюда ссылки нет).

Comment: `Нет времени объяснять!..` =)))

Comment: Не могли бы раскрыть, как вы себе это видите? В том плане, что любая метка может быть обязательной == обязательной будет как минимум одна метка из существующих == так, как работает сейчас.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так, как сейчас на мете. Для задания вопроса нужна хотя бы одна метка из списка обязательных.

Comment: Мета предполагает, что вопрос будет сводиться к заданному набору тем. Мы не можем сказать такого о главном сайте. Пожалуйста, уточните, какие метки вы бы назначили обязательными? Второй вопрос: как от этого улучшиться сайт?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1. Базовые метки, которые позволяют классифицировать вопрос. Определённо, к ним относятся метки-названия языков программирования, операционных систем, некоторые другие. 2. Тут надо много расписывать, на данный момент не могу этого сделать. Плюс, идея несколько спорная и есть разные варианты - по ней самой требуется отдельное обсуждение. 3. На данный момент я спросил, возможно, или нет. Если нет, то я сначала на codegolf'е предложение напишу, поскольку там есть более убедительные причины эту возможность добавить.

Comment: Прямой возможности нет (либо я про нее не знаю). С большой вероятностью, данный запрос будет требовать разработки.